Should each commit in a branch implementing a new feature be prefixed by "feat:" using conventional commits?
Consider I'm working on a branch feat-1 implementing a new feature.
I'm confused what to prefix each commit with on that branch. Should they all be prefixed with feat: (after all, they are all part of implementing a new feature), or should it only be the last commit that's prefixed with feat:?
It's almost impossible to decide whether a commit is the last commit on a branch, and I often find myself going back fixing bugs, introducing new commits, after I thought I made the last commit.
So, I end up with a commit history, like:

infra: adding server
format(ci): fix format of files
feat: implementing feature
ci: adding workflows
fix: bugs in feature
feat: add more functionality
feat: all done

This might be intermixed with chore:s and wip:s.
While, the specification tell us how to "tag" individual commits, I have a hard time translating it to the real world, where multiple commits implement a feature.
https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/

"So, I end up with a commit history, like: ..." - looks good (and as if you already answered your own question from the paragraph above), so what is your question?

@DocBrown All these commits take part of implementing the feature, so why shouldn't they all be prefixed by feat:?

@DocBrown I believe that feat: should only be used on a commit that fully implements the feature. But that's impossible, unless I rebase and squash all commits on the branch, which is often not feasible, as force pushing is disabled

I don't bother with any meaningful or descriptive commits on my branch. Ultimately I do a squash and a single message explaining changes anyway. Disabling force push on all branches is just silly, and will quickly lead to commit noise. Because it doesn't matter how you prefix messages when you have fifty thousand commits.

If you're working in branches, I'd strongly recommend squashing your commits when you merge into your integration branch. At the very least, I'd use interactive rebasing to clean up the commits on the feature branch prior to merging, leaving only the most relevant commits in the history of the integration branch - commits that fix bugs in the newly developed feature, for example, don't mean that much once the working feature is in the integration branch.
If you take the approach of interactively rebasing or squashing when merging to the integration branch, you could consider not using the Conventional Commits annotations for work-in-progress commits that you may make since those commit messages would be removed or changed anyway. Only the commits that end up in the integration branch would need to conform to the standard.
Ewan's answer also brings out a very good point. Not everything needs to be captured in commit messages. Pull requests are a great place to collect a bunch of commits and describe the rational behind changes. In my experience, tools like GitHub and Bitbucket relate the merge commit to the pull request for traceability. Issue trackers also provide a good place for documenting things about a feature over commits. Similarly, both commits and pull requests can be linked to issues. Although Conventional Commits can be helpful, it's not the whole story.

Thank you, but are you able to rebase your feature branch before merging into the integration branch? If you have already pushed commits on the feature branch to the remote, it won't allow the rebased feature branch to be pushed.

@Shuzheng Yes. I don't see a reason why you would prohibit rebase on feature branches, even if they are pushed to remote. I can understand why you'd want to enable branch protection rules on shared branches, like an integration branch, but not on feature branches used by one or a very small number of developers working closely on a change. That is true even if the feature branch is pushed to remote, which I'd consider a good practice to ensure the work is safe in the event something happens to the local workstation.

This. The commit history is documentation. It should be cleaned up and refactored just like any other documentation. We all know you should refactor your code such that it always looks like you knew the correct design and organization from the beginning. In the same vein, you should refactor your commit history such that it looks like you knew the correct logical steps from the beginning.


While, the specification tell us how to "tag" individual commits, I
have a hard time translating it to the real world, where multiple
commits implement a feature.

I think you hit the nail on the head here, If you try and put this kind of knowledge in a commit message, rather than say a linked ticket or PR description then you force yourself into making bigger, tested commits. Rather than the old adage of commit fast and often.
If you try and make your commits "neat" then I think you lose some fundamental benefits of source control. Sharing your code, seeing changes that you can undo, seeing the journey you took.
There are plenty of other places you can use to make "neat" messages. merges, pull requests and a ticketing system are better at this than commit messages
